# In R: Duplicate rows except for the first row based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table dt:

```
names <- c("john","mary","mary","mary","mary","mary","mary","tom","tom","tom","mary","john","john","john","tom","tom")
dates <- c(as.Date("2010-06-01"),as.Date("2010-06-01"),as.Date("2010-06-05"),as.Date("2010-06-09"),as.Date("2010-06-13"),as.Date("2010-06-17"),as.Date("2010-06-21"),as.Date("2010-07-09"),as.Date("2010-07-13"),as.Date("2010-07-17"),as.Date("2010-06-01"),as.Date("2010-08-01"),as.Date("2010-08-05"),as.Date("2010-08-09"),as.Date("2010-09-03"),as.Date("2010-09-04"))
shifts_missed <- c(2,11,11,11,11,11,11,6,6,6,1,5,5,5,0,2)
shift <- c("Day","Night","Night","Night","Night","Night","Night","Day","Day","Day","Day","Night","Night","Night","Night","Day")

df <- data.frame(names=names, dates=dates, shifts_missed=shifts_missed, shift=shift)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

names   dates       shifts_missed   shift
john    2010-06-01  2               Day
mary    2010-06-01  11              Night
mary    2010-06-05  11              Night
mary    2010-06-09  11              Night
mary    2010-06-13  11              Night
mary    2010-06-17  11              Night
mary    2010-06-21  11              Night
tom     2010-07-09  6               Day
tom     2010-07-13  6               Day
tom     2010-07-17  6               Day
mary    2010-06-01  1               Day
john    2010-08-01  5               Night
john    2010-08-05  5               Night
john    2010-08-09  5               Night
tom     2010-09-03  0               Night
tom     2010-09-04  2               Day
```

Ultimately, what I want is to get the following:

```
names   dates       shifts_missed   shift    count
john    2010-06-01  2               Day      1
mary    2010-06-01  11              Night    1
mary    2010-06-05  11              Night    1
mary    2010-06-09  11              Night    1
mary    2010-06-13  11              Night    1
mary    2010-06-17  11              Night    1
mary    2010-06-21  11              Night    1
tom     2010-07-09  6               Day      1
tom     2010-07-13  6               Day      1
tom     2010-07-17  6               Day      1
mary    2010-06-01  1               Day      1
john    2010-08-01  5               Night    1
john    2010-08-05  5               Night    1
john    2010-08-09  5               Night    1
tom     2010-09-03  0               Night    0
tom     2010-09-04  2               Day      1
john    2010-06-01  2               Night    1
mary    2010-06-05  11              Day      1
mary    2010-06-09  11              Day      1
mary    2010-06-13  11              Day      1
mary    2010-06-17  11              Day      1
mary    2010-06-21  11              Day      1
tom     2010-07-09  6               Night    1
tom     2010-07-13  6               Night    1
tom     2010-07-17  6               Night    1
john    2010-08-05  5               Day      1
john    2010-08-09  5               Day      1
tom     2010-09-04  2               Night    1
```

As you can see, the second half of the data is almost a duplicate of the first half. However, if shifts_missed = 0, it should not be duplicated, and if shifts_missed is odd, the first row should not be duplicated but the remaining rows should. It should then add a 1 in the count column for all except when shifts_missed = 0.

I've seen some answers that speak about !duplicate or unique, but these values in shifts_missed are not unique. I'm sure this isn't overly complicated and is probably a multi-step process, but I can't figure out how to isolate the first rows of the odd shifts_missed column.

Comment: There's something I don't get. When you say "the first row should not be duplicated but the remaining rows should," how do you decide which rows are one group. Do they have to have the same "names" and the same "shifts_missed" value? For example, "mary    2010-06-01  1" is not duplicated. Is that because because it is not a continuation of the group that contains "mary    2010-06-21  11"

Comment: A piecemeal `dplyr` solution would be to create the second half of the data table piecemeal: `filter` out shifts_missed == 0, filter for odd shifts_missed and then `group_by` your criteria for duplicates and use `slice(-1)` to cut out the first rows, then finally create a new column using `ifelse`.  Then you can `rbind` this modified table to your original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt[, is.in := if(shifts_missed[1] %% 2 == 0) T else c(F, rep(T, .N-1))
   , by = .(names, shift)]
rbind(dt, dt[is.in & shifts_missed != 0])
```

Adding the extra column part should be obvious.

Comment: This worked really well. Thank you! How can I also have it change the new rows from Day to Night and Night to Day?

Comment: @AndrewRussell `res[, shift := ifelse(shift == 'Day', 'Night', 'Day')]` maybe

Comment: Won't that just change all of them? I only want to switch the new rows that are being added by rbind.

Comment: @AndrewRussell didn't read your comment carefully enough - then just modify that bit: `rbind(dt, dt[...][, shift := ...])`

Comment: That still does the same thing. Unless I'm completely implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: @AndrewRussell start over and make sure you don't omit any brackets - you're probably modifying it in place and not realizing it; this works starting from scratch (after adding `is.in`): `rbind(dt, dt[is.in & shifts_missed != 0][, shift := ifelse(shift == 'Day', 'Night', 'Day')])`